# MVC Binding Dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I am following [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) tutorial. Can anyone please explain to me how I can make the textboxes bind back to the Dictionary? Right now all that happens is the data is being **displayed** in the textboxes - but if I change the textboxes, how do I bind back to the object?. What am I missing? Below is my code:

```
 <input type="text" name="@Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.Title" value="@Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.Title"/>
 <input type="text" name="@Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.PreviewDescription" value="@Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.PreviewDescription"/>
 <input type="text" name="@Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.FullDescription" value="@Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.FullDescription"/>
```

Comment: If possible, consider creating another ViewModel class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` of your text input field is wrong. You have put the value of the model instead of naming it appropriately as explained in the Hanselman's blog post.

So let's assume that you have some view model:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PreviewDescription { get; set; }
    public string FullDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and a main view model containing the dictionary:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, ItemViewModel> ExpirimentToRemove { get; set; }
}
```

and your POST controller action takes this view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Remove(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

In order to correctly bind to this view model you could have the following:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ExpirimentToRemove.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox(
                "ExpirimentToRemove[" + i + "].Key", 
                Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Key
            )
            @Html.TextBox(
                "ExpirimentToRemove[" + i + "].Value.Title", 
                Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.Title
            )
            @Html.TextBox(
                "ExpirimentToRemove[" + i + "].Value.PreviewDescription", 
                Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.PreviewDescription
            )
            @Html.TextBox(
                "ExpirimentToRemove[" + i + "].Value.FullDescription", 
                Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.FullDescription
            )
        </div>
    }

    <p><button type="submit">OK</button></p>
}
```

In this example the key of the dictionary is a simple string value but you could also use a complex type.

Comment: I tried your example. I changed the Key to suit my object. It displays the data successfully but it doesn't save the changes which I make. When I click on Submit and hover over my object at break point, it contains data which was there originally, before the View() was called in the first place.

Comment: Where are you making those changes? In the POST action? In this case you have to clear the ModelState: `ModelState.Clear();` before returning the view, otherwise the TextBox helper will use the initially posted value. Another possibility is to simply hardcode the text inputs instead of using the TextBox helper: `<input type="text" name="ExpirimentToRemove[@i].Value.Title" value="@Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.Title" />`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov this works fine for dictionary but how can I achieve the same with List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> in mvc. The values are displayed in the view fine but when posted all the fields are null

Comment: How can you use an integer as the key for `Dictionary<string, ItemViewModel>`?

Comment: I tried, it show error at Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Key? How to solve it?